# SAML2 SSO - Are query string params supported in EntityId URI

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

Has anyone ever encountered any issues trying to configure a SSO Idp instance where the EntityId contains query string params e.g.

```
https://idpserver.com/IdPServlet?idp_id=12345678
```

Just want to check if there are any known issues with specific formats required for EntityId strings.
We have encountered an error (Http Error 504 during SP login flow) trying to configure a test system with a URI in this format. We also encountered a similar error when the EntityId was just a string of characters and not a full URI e.g. `12345678`

This is only happening in out UAT environment running IIS on AWS. Its working correctly when running locally in dev mode.

Our setup works fine for other SSO configs from IDP providers such as Okta or ADFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the requirement on the EntityID from the spec is that it is an absolute URI. But a query string should be fine, as that is part of a URL and all URLs are also URIs.